# How to create image file in specific location with particular height and width in java

Tags: java, image, opencv

I am implementing the project where i am detecting rectangular object from image. I want to store that part to memory. As the height and width every time i get is not predictable, i am not getting how to store that part of matrix by creating the image file at sd card that will exactly occupy the rectangular object

how can i create image eg . demo.jpg in //temp/  of size 90x50

Comment: Which version of opencv are you using? All you have to do is convert the matrix to a bitmap and save the bitmap to some path.

Answer (score -1):

use php GD function. use code like below

```
header ('Content-Type: image/png');
$im = @imagecreatetruecolor(120, 20)
  or die('Cannot Initialize new GD image stream');
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 233, 14, 91);
imagestring($im, 1, 5, 5,  'A Simple Text String', $text_color);
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

take help from  http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php

Comment: The question is tagget with Java and OpenCV. It has nothing to do with php.